# Como eu posso utilizar o gulp-stylus, jeet e rupture com gulp-load-plugins

Tags: javascript, gulp, stylus

Se eu uso Stylus com Jeet e Rupture, meu gulpfile.js ficaria assim:

```
    .pipe(stylus({  
        use:[prefixer(), jeet(), rupture()],  
        compress: true  
    }))
```

Agora, eu modularizei minhas tarefas do Gulp com o gulp-load-plugins. E então deixei:

```
    .pipe(plugins.stylus({  
        use:[prefixer(), jeet()],  
        compress: true  
    }))
```

Porém, na hora de chamar o gulp no terminal, dá erro. Diz que **jeet is not a function**

```
[14:17:09] Starting 'stylus'...  
[14:17:09] 'stylus' errored after 466 ms  
[14:17:09] ReferenceError: jeet is not defined  
at Gulp. (/home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/tasks/stylus.js:6:22)  
at module.exports (/home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)  
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)  
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)  
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)  
at /home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/tasks/watch.js:6:17  
at write (/home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/node_modules/gulp-watch/index.js:123:9)  
at /home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/node_modules/vinyl-file/index.js:52:4  
at /home/ednilson/Projects/web/workflow/workflow-stylus/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16  
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:404:3)
```

Tentei declarar novamente seguindo orientação da documentação do gulp-load-plugins:

```
    plugins.prefixer = require('autoprefixer-stylus');  
    plugins.jeet = require('jeet');
```

Não deu certo. Então tentei chamar direto na tarefa:

```
    .pipe(plugins.stylus({  
    use:[plugins.prefixer(), plugins.jeet()],  
    compress: true  
    }))
```

```
    .pipe(plugins.stylus({  
        use:[plugins.prefixer(), plugins.jeet()],  
        compress: true  
    }))
```

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Obrigado a todos! :)

Comment: Oi Ednilson, podes traduzir a pergunta para Português?

Comment: Sim, claro.. traduzindo..

Comment: A sintaxe não seria algo como `import: ['jeet/stylus/jeet', ...`? Não conheço esse plugin mto bem, eu uso o Stylus diretamente como Middleware no Node...

Comment: Então, no gulp eu uso apenas chamando o pipe e use[jeet(), rupture()]. Aí no main.styl apenas @import "jeet".

Comment: Estás a usar as ultimas versões desses módulos?

Comment: Sim, as últimas versões de tudo..

Comment: Resolvi. Chamei eles individualmente dentro da task stylus.js.. com const jeet = require('jeet'), Aí ele foi de boa.. obrigado mesmo assim :)